# React-Redux-Saga history.push is updating url, but not loading the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-saga

I am trying to redirect from saga after a password change, and history.push() is just updating the URL not loading the component

**Hisotry.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory as history } from "history";
export default history({
  bforceRefresh: true,
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../../helpers/history";
import Navigation from "../Navigation";
import AppAuthRouter from "../Navigation/routes";
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter history={history}>
    <Navigation app_auth_router={AppAuthRouter} />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
export default App;
```

**AppAuthRouter.js**

```
import * as ROUTES from "../../constants/routes";
import ProtectedRoute from "./protectedroute";
const AppAuthRouter = () => (
  <Switch>
    <ProtectedRoute path="/admin" component={AdminPage} />
    <ProtectedRoute
      path="/updatepwd"
      component={PasswordChangePage}
    />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/welcome" component={WelcomePage} />
    <Route path={"/signup} component={SignUpPage} />
    <Route path={"/signin} component={SignInPage} />
    <Redirect path="*" to={{ pathname:"/signin"}} />
  </Switch>
);
export default AppAuthRouter;
```

**Saga.js**

```
import history from "../helpers/history";
function* passwordChangeSaga({ creds }) {
  try {
    yield put(alertSuccess("Password has been changed successfully"));
    history.push("/welcome");
  } catch (gerror) {
    const error = googleError2Error(gerror);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show us how your routes are defined? We can't see where are you trying to load your components

Comment: updated the question with Routes

Comment: your routes are defined in constasnts; we can't see which one is `welcome`. Please provide all the info required for us (that we don't know your code) to be able to understand what you're trying to achieve and help you

Comment: Updated Constants

Comment: I don't see anything wrong... does the routing work in the other places? Show us the code of your custom "ProtectedRoute"

Comment: You sure you want to use BrowserRouter?

Comment: Yes I need to use BrowserRouter